# Not able to maintain checkbox during pagination using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have 4 buttons for pagination(first,move next,move back and last).
I am trying to maintain checkbox  during pagination. The problem is that
when I select any checkbox and then go to next page and then come back to the same page, it doesn't show previously checked checkbox, but as soon as click on next page, before going to next page it shows value checked.

Here is my code, can anyone guide me where I am doing wrong?

```
    $(function() {
        toggleSelectBtnOnCheck();
    });

    function toggleSelectBtnOnCheck() {
        debugger;
        //Register checkbox click handler to be called when Ajax requests complete.
        $('#contentDiv').ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('.tdHeadForCheckboxRadioButton').append('<input class="search" onclick="checkUnchekAllCheckboxes(this);" type="checkbox"/>');
            $('.afirst, .aprev, .anext, .alast, .search:checkbox').click(function() {
                var selectedVal = $(this).closest('td');
                var selectClaim = selectedVal.next().text();
                var selectSuffix = selectedVal.next().next().text();
                var ClaimSuffix = selectClaim + '|' + selectSuffix + ',';
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    document.getElementById('hdnChkClaim').value += ClaimSuffix;
                } else if ($('#hdnChkClaim').val().indexOf(ClaimSuffix) != -1) {
                    $('#hdnChkClaim').val($('#hdnChkClaim').val().replace(ClaimSuffix, ''));
                }
                alert($('#hdnChkClaim').val());
                if (jQuery(this).attr("href") != "") {
                    //button.disable($('span.btnSelect'));
                    var SelectedItemsCheckboxID = [];
                    if ($('#hdnChkClaim').val() != '') {
                        debugger;
                        if (ClaimSuffix.indexOf(',') != -1) {
                            ClaimSuffix = ClaimSuffix.substr(0, ClaimSuffix.length - 1); //remove last ','
                        }
                        SelectedItemsCheckboxID = $('#hdnChkClaim').val().split(',');
                        for (i = 0; i < SelectedItemsCheckboxID.length; i++) {
                            var claimDetails = SelectedItemsCheckboxID[i].split('|');
                            a = claimDetails[0];
                            b = claimDetails[1];
                            $('tr').filter(function(index) {
                                var columns = $(this).children('td');
                                alert(columns.eq(1).text() === a && columns.eq(2).text() === b);
                                return columns.eq(1).text() === a && columns.eq(2).text() === b;
                            }).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
                            ;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($('.search:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
                        button.enable($('span.btnSelect'));
                    } else {
                        button.disable($('span.btnSelect'));
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the hidden field , when user select a checkbox , add it to hidden field like comma separated Ids , when every page is moved because of pagination check if any of the id in the current page is belong to the hidden field if yes mark them to checked.